# Setting the http status midway through a streamed response

Tags: c#, http-headers

I am streaming an HTTP response and it is erroring midway through the execution, which I have simulated below. The end user is seeing it as a 200 response because I understand that the status is sent in the response header. By the time my error occurs, and I have caught it and reset the status to 500 it is too late. How can I set the "real" status to 500 after I have streamed the original header?

```
var httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
httpResponse.BufferOutput = false;
httpResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";
try
{
    httpResponse.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + Environment.NewLine);
    httpResponse.Write($"<{Constants.XmlHeaderTag}>");
    var theline = 0;
    while (some condition)
    {
        if (theline++ == 3) throw new Exception("Got an error");
        var innerXml = "some xml";
        httpResponse.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(innerXml));
    }
    httpResponse.Write($"</{Constants.XmlHeaderTag}>");
    httpResponse.OutputStream.Flush();
    httpResponse.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    httpResponse.Status = 500;
    logError(ex);
}
```

Comment: Why you want to set it after? It would be much simpler if you prepare whole data and **then** send them wit correct HTTP status.

Comment: The reason why is because the response is too large to prepare in memory and send, it has to be streamed.

Comment: side note: you'll be chewing up a lot of `byte[]` allocations from that `GetBytes` call; if you see memory pressure, you might want to look at whether you can avoid that, perhaps writing directly to the output stream and/or using a scratch buffer for the encode step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The http header *is before* the data in the payload. Once the headers are sent: they are sent. You cannot set the header after this, and even if you could, no client would understand what you meant, since there's no way to *receive* the header during the payload. All you can do is kill the response; the client will know that they haven't got everything (assuming you sent a content-length header), and the xml will be malformed (not correctly terminated), so they'll figure out that it is broken sooner or later.